# Canasta opening with jokers

Tags: canasta

Can you open with 5 wild cards, then use a sixth to put with a pair?

My partner needed 155 points and this is the only way they could open.

Comment: What do you mean by your partner needing 155 points? That's not one of the possible values of a minimum meld.

Comment: We start at 125, the. 155, then 180. Canasta

Comment: Just a house rule?

Answer (score 3):

No.

Any valid meld in Canasta needs to have at least 2 naturals in it, so wilds by themselves are not enough.

From Bicycle:

> A meld is valid if it contains at least two natural cards of the same rank - aces down to fours inclusive - and not more than three wild cards. Jokers and deuces may never be melded apart from natural cards.

Note that there is a variation of this rule that is seen in some places; according to canasta.net:

> However, there may never be more wildcards than natural cards within one meld.

In most situations, these 2 rules work the same way; they both mean that a meld of 3 -7 cards must have at least as many naturals as wilds.

The difference is that one of the rules allows you to add a 4th wild to a Canasta that has 4 naturals and 3 wilds, while the other does not, but this rarely could matter, as you can likely just add that wild somewhere else instead if you need to.